# Web player does not appear in Build Settings

Tags: web, unity-game-engine

Web player option does not appear in File -> Build Settings.

I have installed Unity Web Player, and my version of Unity is Unity 5.4.1f1 (64-bit)

I've installed the plugin throught Unity's web too, and restarted Unity.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity Web Player has been [discontinued](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta/unity5.4.0f1) and removed from Unity completely in 5.4 release. You have to download the WebGL module and build your game for WebGL. Users were warned about and encouraged to make their code work with WebGL last year

> Web: WebPlayer support has been removed, and the default player is now
>   the platform desktop being run on for the Editor. Therefore desktop
>   platform installation choices are no longer available for their
>   respective editors.

Comment: Some tutorials (such as Space Shooter) on the Unity site target the Web Player, so this is not so obvious to beginners.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.